# Does anybody know a slingshot replacement solution for elementary OS?

Tags: slingshot

Does anybody know a way to replace the slingshot (5x3 application launcher) with something like the Gnome application launcher? The problem is that it is not usefull for me to scroll(or click for a category and scroll) to find the application launcher I need.

Comment: Just use ulancher instead https://ulauncher.io/

Answer (score 0):

I think this article will help you. Thank you for having this question, I forgot that such a tool can go faster when we know what is on his system.

https://www.fossmint.com/best-application-launchers-for-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I have already discovered a few more websites with top5,top20 etc Linux app launchers, but all of them text based.. When I'm using the keyboard the slingshot do the job pretty well, but the problem is when I want to use only the mouse.. I have more then 50 apps installed and the list is growing. So I don't feel comfortable to scroll like crazy back and forth 3x5 grid pages using 1/6 part of my computer screen to found the app I need.. On Juno there was a setting with dconf that I can make this grid 13x6 which was really usefull but in Hera there is no such an option....